# Swift NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData() not able to read data for "OK" String only

Tags: ios, json, swift

This might be the strangest thing I have encountered.  We have decided to move on from it but I wanted to make a post to try and understand.

So I am grabbing some JSON data from our server and everything seems to work just fine except for the string "OK".

Here is the function :

```
func getRequest(token:String, url:String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if data != nil && response != nil{
            do{
                let responseTest = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if responseTest != nil{
                    let response:NSDictionary = responseTest!
                    callback(response)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError{
                print("A JSON parsing error occured: \(error)")

            }
        } else {
            callback(NSDictionary())
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

The data comes back form the call and then the response parses all of the data correctly except for the status "OK" which came back with unable to read data.  We changed the status to "Success" and it worked just fine.  We tested out a bunch of different words and they all worked just fine except the word "OK" which always came back with Unable to read data.  Strangest thing I have every seen.  For now we are going to go with a status of "Success" but, I just can't get this out of my head.  WHY?!?!  What is different about those 2 letters?  Anyone else run into this or just have an understanding that I seem to be lacking?  It is driving me crazy.

Here is the JSON from one of our attempts:

{"username":"gang_su","status":"0K","status2":"This is much more OK","status3":"OK OK OK","status4":"OK","status5":true,"status6":123,"status7":12345.678,"status8":[1,2,3,4],"status9":[1.02,2.02,3.02,4.02]}

Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds crazy, can you post your raw json?

Comment: Yes it does.  I added the JSON to the post.

Comment: Note that `'OK`' has single quotes. See: [Introducing JSON](http://www.json.org).

Comment: Sorry about that.  I grabbed that JSON from an email...not sure why the single quotes were there.  Thought my friend copied it straight from the code.  I updated it now with the JSON that is currently coming from the server.  I copied it straight from the view source page in my browser.

Comment: Great, that updated JSON is valid. But that JSON doesn't manifest the problem you describe. We cannot help you without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. In answer to your question, there is absolutely nothing special about "OK", but rather there is something else going elsewhere in your code (or in the server response).

Comment: The way we tested it was to go into that JSON on the server and replace the 'O' in ok with a '0'(that is a zero) and didn't change anything else.  It worked just fine for "0k".  I guess I could recreate the project but that would take too long.  I just wanted to understand.  For now we will just avoid that word.  Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2):

```
{ username: req.user.username, status: 'OK', status2: "This is much more OK" }
```

The above "JSON" has single quotes around OK.  This is invalid JSON.

It's not OK, you might say.

They need to be double quotes, as you have used in your other strings.

Comment: Yea that JSON was incorrect.  Sorry, I have updated it with the most current JSON we are using.  He have added in a bunch of stuff to test it.  They all work except for status4

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in a playground, and it works fine with your provided example JSON. The logical conclusion is that that's not actually the data you're passing in.

You might want to dump that NSData to the console, or to a file, and check for any unexpected characters.